# saving cvs file in python

Tags: python, csv, save, biopython

I am having trouble saving my data into a csv file. I am trying to separate the amino acids in this gene into four groups non polar (np), polar (p), negative (neg), and positive (pos). I have figured out how to count all the single amino acids and save them into a cvs file, but cannot figure out how to save the data from the four groups in the same way as with the single amino acids.

Here is the code for the single amino acids saving into the csv:

```
from Bio import Entrez, SeqIO

Entrez.email = ""

handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", id="KT191142", rettype="gb", retmode="text")
record = SeqIO.read(handle, "genbank")
handle.close()

protein_seq = record.seq.translate()
print(protein_seq)

def count_aa(seq, csv_file):

aa_dict = {} # dictionary to store amino acid counts

for aa in seq:

    if aa in aa_dict:
        aa_dict[aa] += 1 # increment the count of an amino acid by 1
    else:
        aa_dict[aa] = 1 # set the count of an amino acid to 1

with open(csv_file, "w") as file:

    aa_list=sorted(aa_dict.keys())

    file.write("amino_acid,count\n")

    for aa in aa_list:
        line = str(aa) + ',' + str(aa_dict[aa]) + '\n'

        file.write(line)

count_aa(protein_seq, "ebola_aa_count2.csv")`
```

I want to save this new code into a csv file just like in this previous code, here is the new code:

```
import re

handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", id="KT191142", rettype="gb", retmode="text")
records = SeqIO.read(handle, "genbank")
handle.close()

protein_seq = records.seq.translate()
print(protein_seq)

np_count = 0
p_count = 0
neg_count = 0
pos_count = 0

for aa in protein_seq:
    match_np = re.search(r"G|A|V|C|P|L|I|M|W|F", str(aa))
    match_p = re.search(r"S|T|Y|N|Q", str(aa))
    match_neg = re.search(r"D|E", str(aa))
    match_pos = re.search(r"K|R|H", str(aa))
    if match_np:
        np_count += 1
    if match_p:
        p_count += 1
    if match_neg:
        neg_count += 1
    if match_pos:
        pos_count += 1

handle.close()
print(np_count, p_count, neg_count, pos_count)
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to manipulate csv files.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['np_count', 'p_count', 'neg_count', 'pos_count'], data =[np_count, p_count, neg_count, pos_count])
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```